# npm no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, package.json

I am fairly new to node and, when trying to use a third party node template, I am receiving the following error:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Ryan/package.json'
```

---

This is the error with the directory it is referring me to side-by-side.

[image: IMG]

---

**Now The file it is referring me to simply does not exist, or I haven't found it.**

I assume that that `node_modules` directory is presumably some sort of base directory so..

is it missing something?

Or is it not supposed to be there completely?

And, most importantly, how does that directory relate to this error?

---

Steps I have taken after initial research:

- Uninstalling/Re-Installing Node with Homebrew
- Installing Express in this directory
- re-running the "npm install ..." command multiple times (apparently that helped some people at some points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error appears is because npm packages should be installed either inside an npm project, or for global usage specifing the -g flag after npm install.
You aren't inside  a node project folder (which are characterized by a package.json file) and you're not specifing the -g flag so npm is throwing a warning

If you need to use that library inside a project install it from within its root directory,otherwise specify the -g flag if you need to use the library as a command line utility